# React JS useEffect hook executing when another useEffect still isn't finished

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern

I have two useEffects in my functional component, in which useEffect 1 is executed first and then useEffect 2 is executed based on the useState value in useEffect 1 but if you see the log below, useEffect 2 is executed in the middle of useEffect 1 (which hasn't finished yet)

Is this normal behaviour or am I doing anything wrong? Help in this regard is much appreciated. I am a beginner learning MERN Stack.

I want to get the response from API call first and then only execute useEffect 2.

Thanks in advance

```
const Messenger = () => {
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);

    const state = useRef(useLocation().state); // useRef to change value and persist it for every re-render
    console.log(state)

    const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);

// Get the conversations if any from DB
     useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect 1")
        console.log("get Conversations if any")
        const getAllConversations = async () => {
            try {
                localStorage.setItem("user", user);
                const res = await getConversationsAPI(user?._id)
                console.log(res.data)
                setConversations(res.data);
                console.log("Set conversations:")
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            localStorage.removeItem("user");
        };
        getAllConversations();
    }, [user]);

useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect 2")
        if (state?.current) {
            console.log("Conversation already Exists useEffect")
            for (let convo of conversations) {
                console.log(convo)
                if (convo?.members.some(mem => mem._id === state?.current?._id)) { 
                    console.log("Conversation already exists..", state?.current._id)
                    state.current = null;
                    console.log(state.current)
                };
            };
        };
}, [state, conversations]); 

[Log] useEffect 1 
[Log] get Conversations if any 
[Log] Get Conversations API: User 
[Log] Bef api: – "632d33562aafdba7835b30ac" 
[Log] useEffect 2 
[Log] Conversation already Exists useEffect 
[Log] Aft api: – "632d33562aafdba7835b30ac" 
[Log] [Object, Object] (2)
[Log] Set conversations: 
[Log] useEffect 2
[Log] Conversation already Exists useEffect 
[Log] {_id: "634cf4adb10c58cd8b248591", members: Array, createdAt: "2022-10-17T06:22:37.985Z", updatedAt: "2022-10-17T06:22:37.985Z", __v: 0} 
[Log] Conv already exists..state – "632c208f8bb1b20a5604f210" 
[Log] null 
[Log] {_id: "634e3ff52834916e46595fff", members: Array, createdAt: "2022-10-18T05:56:05.990Z", updatedAt: "2022-10-18T05:56:05.990Z", __v: 0} 
[Log] {current: null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's normal behavior. All `useEffect`s will run at least once.

I see your second effect depends on `state`. If you can overcome that dependency, you could just use one `useEffect`. You would run your logic that handles the result from the API in the first effect itself, just after the `setConversations`.

If for some reason you do depend on `state`, in your scenario, you could create a state to mark when the conversations are loaded (e.g., `conversationsLoaded`) and then use that state in the second effect to make sure you only execute your logic after the conversations were loaded. Example:

```js
const Messenger = () => {
    // ...

    const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
    const [conversationsLoaded, setConversationsLoaded] = useState(false);

     useEffect(() => {
        const getAllConversations = async () => {
            try {
                // ...
                const res = await getConversationsAPI(user?._id)
                setConversations(res.data);
                setConversationsLoaded(true);
            } catch (err) {
            // ...
        };
        getAllConversations();
    }, [user]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // ...
        if (conversationsLoaded) {
            // now you know conversations were loaded and can work with them safely
        }
        // ...
    }, [state, conversationsLoaded, ...]);
```

Comment: Thank you acdcjunior @karthiksivasubramaniam.. I used both your answers to solve my problem.

Comment: I checked one logic like this `if (state?.current && conversations?.length > 0)` and another one like this `//if no conversations exist create the conversation
        if (state?.current && apiExecuted)`

Answer (score 1):

the second `useEffect` is going to fire right away no matter what.. then after that it will wait for values to change in the dependency array.  does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `useEffect-2` you can simply add a flag on api response and based on that flag state execute what you want.

a rough example can be like:-

on api response `flag = true`
and after this write a function outside useEffect

```
if(flag){

..whaterver you want to execute..

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` runs once when the component initially mounts, and runs again every time one of the dependencies passed to it changes. You can't prevent the execution of `useEffect` itself, but if you want to execute the logic inside it after some conditions are met, there is a simple workaround.

When you say you want to run one `useEffect` after another, you mean that you want one piece of code to produce an outcome before another runs. In your case, I assume that you want all the conversations loaded before your code inside useEffect 2 runs.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (conversations.length) {
            // do whatever you need to in useEffect 2
        }
}, [state, conversations]);
```